# Month issue in SimpleDateFormat class

Tags: java, android, datetime, simpledateformat

```
String expiryDate = "2016-03-14";
private String formatDateTime(String expiryDate, String expiryTime) {
    SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM, dd, yyyy");
    try {
        String formattedDate = output.format(input.parse(expiryDate ));// parse input
        return  formattedDate + ", " + expiryTime;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

However when it returns it gives Jan, 14, 2016.

The desired output was Mar,14,2016

Comment: `mm` should  be capital `MM`

Comment: In what format do you want??

Comment: @MD thanks your solution worked.Can you post as an answer will accept that

Comment: Whenever `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't do what you expect, *always, always* check the documentation and double-check your format pattern.

Comment: @FarazDurrani Yeah right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mm` should be capital `MM`. Beacuse

**mm** represent minute
  **MM** represent Month

So your format should be like

```
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 3):

mm represents minutes, so when you use mm, it will print minutes instead of month.

While MM represents months. You need to add like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

should be

```
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

mm should be MM

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

There is a correction need to be made in the above statement as below:

```
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Use MM instead mm as MM is used for month while mm is used for Minutes.

Answer (score 1):

`java.text.SimpleDateFormat` internally calls `java.util.Locale` which have actual implementation of Date Time and Region Format Pattern. So, In `Locale`**MM** is Defined for Month and **mm** for minutes. So, Using

`SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");` will not match any pattern so by default month will set to its default `1`. and it displayed to `Jan` instead of `Mar`(Which u actually Expecting).

Use **MM** for represent Month. It will solve your issue.

```
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been answered already, the other answers are correct. I should like to provide the modern version of your method.

```
private static DateTimeFormatter output
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM, dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

private static String formatDateTime(String expiryDate, String expiryTime) {
    String formattedDate = LocalDate.parse(expiryDate).format(output);
    return  formattedDate + ", " + expiryTime;
}
```

When I call this method with an `expiryDate` of `2016-03-14`, I get `Mar, 14, 2016` back as expected.

### java.time

The `SimpleDateFormat` that you are using (and that the other answers use too) is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. I recommend you forget about it and instead use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Your input format, `2016-03-14`, agrees with ISO 8601, the format that the modern classes parse as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter. So there isn’t even a chance to get the case of `MM` wrong in the format pattern string.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.