# How can I add one month to change into the milliseconds?

Tags: java, android, firebase, milliseconds, date

I have a problem changing the current time into milliseconds, the milliseconds shown one month before the set date and time. I know the computer starts the months at 0, how can I solve the problem? First, I transfer the date and the time into `String`, then I convert the `String` into date in `SimpleDateFormat`, and then I convert the date into `Long`.

For example: When the user enter the date "2018/2/14 11:18 "(AM),  the date convert to long is "1515899940000"  .

Here is my code:

```
private void  setDateField() {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    int yy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mm = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dd = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, mm);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dd);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, yy);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog ,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDate) {

            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDate;
            date_time = year + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + day;
            timePicker();
        }
    },year, month, day);

    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
    datePickerDialog.show();

}

private void timePicker(){
    // Get Current Time
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    // Launch Time Picker Dialog
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog,new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,int minute) {

                    hours = hourOfDay;
                    minutes = minute;
                    string_date = date_time+" "+format(hours) + ":" +format(minutes) ;
                    addtime.setText(string_date);
                    Log.e("JEJEJEJE",string_date);

                    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm");
                    try {
                        Date d = f.parse(string_date);
                        milliseconds = d.getTime();
                        Log.e("LONGGGGGGG", String.valueOf(milliseconds));
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, hours, minutes, true);
    timePickerDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: It’s very unclear to me, sorry. Could you state *precisely* the desired result and the difference between the observed and the desired result? Also a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) could help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Month in simple date formatter always return JANUARY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184541/month-in-simple-date-formatter-always-return-january). And/or of [Month issue in SimpleDateFormat class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645551/month-issue-in-simpledateformat-class).

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: did you check out those month issue questions I linked to? I’m in earnest when I say I think they will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest: First, instead of your variables (fields?) `year`, `month`, `day`, `hours` and `minutes` just declare

```
private LocalDate date;
private LocalTime time;
private long milliseconds;
```

(Keep the `milliseconds` variable since you will want to have your result here.)

In `onDateSet` assign a value to `date` in this way:

```
        date = LocalDate.of(selectedYear, selectedMonth + 1, selectedDate);
```

This is where we are taking into account, as you said, that the date picker’s `selectedMonth` is 0-based, while `LocalDate` numbers months the way humans do, from 1.

Now your `timePicker` method becomes

```
private void timePicker(){
    // Get Current Time
    time = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    // Launch Time Picker Dialog
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,int minute) {

                    time = LocalTime.of(hourOfDay, minute);

                    milliseconds = date.atTime(time)
                            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                            .toInstant()
                            .toEpochMilli();
                    Log.e("LONGGGGGGG", String.valueOf(milliseconds));
                }
            },
            time.getHour(),
            time.getMinute(),
            true);
    timePickerDialog.show();

}
```

You were greatly overcomplicating things. I recommend:

1. Don’t use strings for dates or times in your business logic, use date and time objects. This also means you’ve got no need for a formatter like `SimpleDateFormat` (which, I might add, is notoriously troublesome, so it is good that you can do without it).
2. Use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with than the old-fashioned date and time classes like `Calendar`.

The two points go hand in hand in the above snippets. Also as far as I can see you have no use for the `Calendar` object (`c`) in `setDateField`, just remove it and all use of it.

### What went wrong in your code?

The culprit was your `SimpleDateFormat`. Try using it like this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm");
    System.out.println(f.parse("2018/04/17 12:45"));
```

On my computer this prints

```
Wed Jan 17 12:45:00 CET 2018
```

It prints a date in January no matter what is in the string. This is because you tried lowercase `mm` for month. `mm` is for minutes (which you also used correctly), month is uppercase `MM`. So your formatter cannot parse a month at all and assigns your date the default month, which is the first month of the year, January. And this date in January was of course also what went into your millesecond value.

### Question: Can I use `java.time` on Android?

Yes, you can use `java.time` on Android. Using it just requires Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and newer Android versions the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310, where the modern API was first described).
- On older Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. Make sure you import the date and time classes from package `org.threeten.bp` and subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation of Calendar object](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int))

`Calendar` object offers to us method such as `getTimeInMillis()` and `add(int field, int amount)`. Adding looks like `add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)`

Comment: I've add it but when I want to let the User pick the time it starts one month after the current time.

Comment: i'm not sure what you want to do. You want to add time to which date?